# Composite WPF Visual Studio Style Interface

Tags: wpf, prism

I am looking to design an interface in the style of the Visual Studio interface with WPF Composite Application Guidance (PRISM). I would like to have a tree on the left with the different views that can be opened. When some one clicks on a node in the tree, have the view open on the right in a tab. If the view is already opened in the tab, bring it to the front. I would also like the tree to be in sync with the active tab.

I've tried searching for some articles on this with no luck. Does anyone have any links or information on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should start with MVVM first. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Infragistics has a [xamDockManager](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/xamdockmanager.aspx#Overview) control that will do a lot of the work for you.  I have not used this particular control, but I have used some of their other WPF controls with varied success.